# Android Card Emulation with HostApduService gives different tag ID each time, can't ignore it

Tags: android, nfc, emv

So in my case one phone works as a reader and the other works as an emulated card using HostApduService. My problem right now is that if I touch these phones the reader will start reading the other phone that emulates the card multiple times a second. I fixed this issue when reading plastic emv cards simply by using `nfcAdapter.ignore(tag, ...)`. But when I read a phone it always has a different tag ID, which is why I guess the `nfcAdapter.ignore` does nothing and it rapidly reads the phone that emulates the card.

Is there any way to ignore other phone after reader reads it? Most optimal would be to somehow have static tag ID on other phone.

Of course easiest way would be to disabling reading for some time after I read the phone once but I would like to make `nfcAdapter.ignore` work or other nicer solution.

Comment: Are you in control of the HostApduService? if yes, just add your own ID to data response and then your reader can read it silently and then ignore it.

Comment: Yes I am in control of it. Problem is that the system will still keep reading it and keep vibrating and playing a sound on the reader phone.

Comment: I guess you are using `enableForegroundDispatch` to read the Tag? If yes move to `enableReaderMode` as you can turn off the sound to silently read the Tag.

Comment: Yeah this could work. And if I still need some indication I guess I could vibrate it manually after it reads the phone a single time.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes I ignore all Tags at various times using `enableReaderMode` and then do the vibration and sound myself. Doing it this way also is also much more reliable for write operations as the user only gets the sound after the write operation not on the Tag coming in to range (and then they move the Tag out of range because they heard the sound)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your own ID to data response of the HostApduService and then your reader can read it silently and then ignore it by using the [enableReaderMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter#enableReaderMode(android.app.Activity,%20android.nfc.NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)) API with the `FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS` flag.

You can then choose yourself to make the notification sound/vibration (so it looks like the HostApduService Tag has been ignored).

As background in NFC by design the UID of Tags only needs to be Unique when multiple Tags are in range at the same time, thus Emulated Tags use a random ID for security purposes as this meets this requirement while making the phone untrackable via it's UID (plus also there is probably not enough UID's available to make it actually Unique)